# Api.ai fails to retrieve parameters value

Tags: dialogflow-es

Here's what's in my intent:

[image: Intent screenshot]

API.AI seems to resolve the query correctly (red boxes)

It also invokes the right action (blue box and blue arrow)

But the parameter value of "flightId" is empty where it should be 78160 (green boxes)

What is the reason of the problem and why is the score only 0.67?

**Update**: I just wonder if this is a problem with api.ai because when I remove webhook fulfilment (not shown in the picture), the parameter value for flightId is still empty. BTW, this worked yesterday with a webhook fulfiment. The problem is the parameter value for flightId is missing before any code in the webhook gets executed.

Comment: Has the flight id (78160) been annotate in the user says example as the flightId entity?

Comment: @matthewayne Can you please rephrase your question with punctuations. I am not following what you are asking. Thanks

Comment: Has "78160" been annotated as the flightId entity in the "user says" example in the intent?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. The picture does not show, but the problem was I unknowingly created a new entity type called @flightId. The new entity type works similar to an enum type.  The first time I ran it, the value was added to the enum collection (can be seen in the entities page) automatically. When I ran with any other values, the parameter will be empty. Until I add them to the enum collection (annotate as matthewayne called it).

So to fix, the problem, I removed the new entity type @flightId completely. No need to make a new entity type. Just make it a @sys.any. There might be some other built-in types that might work as well (@sys.any does not seem like too strongly-typed).

Side note: Now that I read matthewayne's 3rd comment, it kind of makes sense. But the term annotate didn't mean much to me in the beginning.